# How to wrap every Rails ActiveRecord query using an around_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to create a module that when included, makes every active record query execute as a block that I will wrap.

Specifically I'm using https://github.com/zendesk/active_record_shards to shard to multiple databases. In this scenario we have 10 duplicate databases (same schema but different client instances) and 1 unique database. By default, any calls to our models that belong to the 10 duplicate databases will be wrapped in an application controller around_action that does

```
ActiveRecord::Base.on_shard(database_name) do
  yield
end
```

However we have a set of models that should only execute queries against this 1 unique database. Rather than execute every ActiveRecord query on those models using something like

```
ActiveRecord::Base.on_shard('unique_db') { Model.find(id) }
```

I would rather make a module that when included executes the active record query as a block inside the on_shard method so they always execute agains the unique_db

Let me know if I'm going down the wrong path and should just stick with my helper method which basically just shortens the length

```
module UniqeDB
  def self.exec!
    ActiveRecord::Base.on_shard('unique_db') do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Update: 
I was able to do something like this, however it overrides every method with (*args, &block) however some methods (like default_scope) only take a block and then it throws exceptions

```
included do
  ActiveRecord::Base.methods.each do |name|
    define_singleton_method name do |*args, &block|
      ActiveRecord::Base.on_shard('unique_db') do
        super(*args, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Update: I opened an issue with the gem to see if there is something i'm missing
https://github.com/zendesk/active_record_shards/issues/87

Comment: Wouldn't you just used their `not_sharded` stuff per https://github.com/zendesk/active_record_shards#usage ? (I don't know anything about the gem, but that seems like what you want)

Comment: I have tried making unique_db as my default database in the database.yml and then keep my 10 client databases as the shards (previously the default database was 1 client test db) and then adding not_sharded to unique_db models. Rails server won't launch because it when it launches I think it tries to query the client db models schemas against the unique_db since its now default. I wonder if I'm not using the gem as intended.

Answer (score 0):

> Include the below module in any controller like '**include ExecuteInUniqueDB**'
>
> > All action inside the controller will only in **unique_db**

```
module ExecuteInUniqueDB
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      around_action :run_on_unique_db
    end
  end

  def run_on_unique_db(&block)
    ActiveRecord::Base.on_shard('unique_db', &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: This would make any action on the controller run against the unique db as you have stated. However I need just queries against a set of models to go to that db. 1 controller action will primarily pull from models on the sharded client databases, but will need to also make some calls to the unique_db modles. Ideally said module would be included on those models and basically do an around_action for all active record queries (although I think around_action only works for controller actions ) :(